# Android studio WebView - download complete but can't open file

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a png image from a website which requires authentication. I am using this code:

```
 mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            //request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```

It shows that the download was complete but I can't open the image. I tried to download the image from browser and I compared a image sizes. The image downloaded from the webview was 5KB, but the one from the browser (which can be opened) was 100KB.
When I add this line `request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);` to the DownloadListener the download won't start. At least it won't show as a notafication, however after about 5 minutes a notafication pops up that the download was unsuccessful.